# Add some number to a variable and print

Tags: jquery

Can you please help me, I've searched all over and I can't seem to find a simple way of doing this.

This code, for example adds '+1' every time its execuded:

```
$('#LoadProgressMessage').html('<h6>'+ ++PercentLoaded + '% Loaded</h6>');
```

But what if I want to add an extra 2, 3 or 4?

Thank you! :))

Comment: While this is not inherently a bad question as you've explained your problem clearly and provided some code, this really is coding 101. Try googling for a syntax guide as it would probably give you a better reference.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I will do so next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var num = 2; // used a var in case it's used in more than one place.
$('#LoadProgressMessage').html('<h6>'+ (num + PercentLoaded) + '% Loaded</h6>');
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the help! I tried this and it worked perfectly, however for some reason it doesn't work on my site. For example, [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXxQZ/) works nicely, but [creates NaN](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia8/) on the site. Even replacing `= PercentLoaded+imageload;` with `= PercentLoaded+4;` doesn't seem to work.